# Emacs -- debugging an overlay that is one character too wide

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some assistance, please, debugging the second example -- it should be only one (1) character wide, but ends up being two (2) characters wide.

---

***WORKING* EXAMPLE**:  The following code creates an overlay of just one (1) character wide, which is *correct*:

```lisp
(let ((my-column (current-column)))
  (overlay-put
    (make-overlay
      (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (+ (point) my-column))
      (+ 1 (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (+ (point) my-column)) ) )
    'face '(background-color . "pink")))
```

---

***BROKEN* EXAMPLE**:  The following code creates an overlay that is two (2) characters wide, which is *incorrect*:

```lisp
(let ((my-column (current-column)))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\n" nil t)
      (overlay-put
        (make-overlay
          (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (+ (point) my-column))
          (+ 1 (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (+ (point) my-column)) ) )
        'face '(background-color . "pink"))) ))
```

---

**EDIT -- *FIXED* EXAMPLE**:  Based on the helpful guidance of @Lindydancer in the answer below, here is the revised example that now works -- perhaps it could be simplified, but at least I now understand the concept:

```lisp
(let* (
    (my-column (current-column))
    my-line-beginning
    my-line-ending
    my-line-length)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\n" nil t)
      (setq my-line-beginning (point))
      (end-of-line)
      (setq my-line-ending (point))
      (setq my-line-length (- my-line-ending my-line-beginning))
      (when (< my-column my-line-length)
        (overlay-put
          (make-overlay
            (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (+ (point) my-column))
            (+ 1 (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (+ (point) my-column)) ) )
          'face '(background-color . "pink"))) )))
```

Comment: Consider making use of functions `line-end-position` (aka `point-at-eol`) and `line-beginning-position` (aka `point-at-bol`), instead of fiddling with `end-of-line` and `beginning-of-line`.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for helping me to make the function more efficient -- :) -- your suggestion certainly is much better than my moving the point all over the buffer to obtain the same information.

Comment: A character can consume more than 1 column (think TABs, chinese double-width chars, or escape chars displayed as \NNN or ^C).  So better use `move-to-column`.

Comment: @Stefan -- a few hours after reading your comment and wrestling with TABs, a light bulb finally turned on inside my head -- `move-to-column` does indeed fix the problems I've been experiencing.  Thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you add the overlay to all lines. If the line is shorter than `my-column`, the overlay will spill over lines below, giving the impression that some overlays are two character wide, when in reality it's two one-character overlays placed next to eachother.

Try to limit the code to put the overlay only on lines that are at least `my-overlay` long.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to understand what was happening -- greatly appreciated!!!  I've posted a working example as an edit to my question -- perhaps it could be more efficient, but I at least understand the concept now thanks to you.